# (Python) Cannot find any items in imported module scrapy

Tags: python, directory, scrapy

I started a project using scrapy on this path `C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\Project_Website\Scrapy`

The problem is that most of my items imported are not found.
For example in `quotes.py` it succesfully imports module scrapy but it can't open its items:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):   # Error Cannot find reference Spider in imported module scrapy
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/']          
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
         pass
```

similarly in my `items.py` file:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpiderItem(scrapy.Item):   # Error Cannot find reference 'item' in imported module scrapy
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Here's my project directory:

```
Scrapy>
  quotes_spider>
       quotes_spider>
             spiders>
                  __init__.py
                  quotes.py
             __init__.py
             items.py
             middlewares.py
             pipelines.py
             settings.py
       scrapy.cfg
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: Which version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: The latest one, Scrapy 1.3.2. I don't think there's anything wrong with both scrapy and my python because it worked when I take away the `/Scrapy` main directory, but when I put everything inside it,  it's giving me instantly this error.

Comment: Your versions for Python and Scrapy sound fine. Check what I wrote below regarding your log.  You should get 200 for your respond of the GET

Comment: Yeah @Dave S everything is working well, that's why it's surprising that it's not recognizing them.

Comment: are you getting these files quotes-1.html and quotes-2.html??

Comment: I think I fixed it. Apparently when I opened my file on Pycharm from the `Scrapy` main directory it gave me errors but when I opened it from the `quotes_spider>`dir as my main. It fixed everything. It was probably a problem with the PyCharm and directories hierarchies. Thanks for the help anyways man.

Comment: Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are working with the tutorial, but what you posted is incomplete which makes it hard to see what is going on in your case.

I would double check your code.  If it looks correct, check your log output.

The log should look something like this:

```
[ ... Scrapy log here ... ]
2016-09-19 12:09:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET    http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fa91d888c90>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
[s]   response   <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fa91d888c10>
```

Check that your return code on the response is 200.

More information can be found here:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Good luck!

Comment: Where can I get the log output?

Comment: You should be able to see the output if you run the Scrapy shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory name `Scrapy` is conflicting with `import scrapy` in Pycharm

I had the same issue, simply change your top-level directory name